# Rstudio and R capabilities() are not the same?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a question about `R` and `Rstudio` `capabilities()`.

I installed `R-3.3.2` and here is the output of `capabilities()` in `R` :

```
 >capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Then I installed `Rstudio1.1`, and when I run `capabilities()` on `Rstudio`, `the capabilities()` are not the same (for exemple for cairo) :

```
    >capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE
```

I verified if `Rstudio` runs the right version of `R` and yes it does.

I found nothing related to this kind of problem on other posts.

Comment: but is it running the _same R binary_? Just b/c the version is the same does not mean it's not picking up a different R binary.

Comment: @hrbrmstr How would you verify which binary its using?

Comment: I checked that by running `Sys.which("R")`, here the binary is the same, but maybe it is not the right command?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Comment: I saw this article, and my variable `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` is already on the same binary as `R`.

Comment: `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` will tell you the root of your R system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded R to the newest version (3.4.2) and it is now working.